# how to check for duplicates list text before adding it to the list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Let say I have the following ul List:

```
                  <ul id='testList'>

                            <li>dfsdfdsfs</li>
                            <li>dfsdfdsfs</li>
                            <li>dfsdfdsfs</li>
                            <li>dfsdfdsfs</li>
                            <li>dfsdfdsfs</li>
                  </ul>
```

Next, I need to check this list for duplicates before adding an item to the list:

```
                 $("#testList li").each(function()
                 {
                     if(output == $(this).text())
                     { 
                            alert("duplicate entry");
                     }else
                     {
                         $("#testList").append("<li>"+output+"</li>");
                     }

                 });
```

Problem, the else statement is not being added when the list is empty...

Comment: You have no `id="testList"`, only `class="testList"`

Comment: sorry typo and the problem remains

Comment: What is the contents of `output`?

Comment: you are running else on every comparison, instead of over all the comparisons together. why not set a boolean if we found a duplicate, and after all comparisons test this boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has several problems. First it doesn't add anything if the list is empty, second of all, it will add elements that are unequal to any of the items within the list, third: testList is a class and $("#testList") looks for an id.

Try this:

```
           function addToList() {
             var addit = true;
             $("testList li").each(function()
             {
                 if(output == $(this).text())
                 { 
                        addit = false;
                 }
             });
             if(addit)
                 $("testList").append("<li>"+output+"</li>");
           }
```